# Removing the end node from a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

What am I missing to allow me to remove a node(boxcar) to the end of my linked list?

```
public void removeBoxcarFromEnd() {

    Boxcar prevcar = head;
    Boxcar nextcar = head;

    if (head.next == null) {
        int result = head.data;
        head = null;
        return result;
    }    
    else {
        while (nextcar.next() > 2)
        prevcar = nextcar;
        nextcar = nextcar.next();
    }
    prevcar.setNext(null);
    size--;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - a (short) complete code sample that **can actually compile** (unless you have a question about getting it to compile), that you **tested** and **found an issue** with, and then **describe the issue** in the question.

Comment: Btw: you have a function with a return type of `void`, but you write `return result;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with this approach:

- you're method is a `void` whereas you want to return the data of the last item?
- your while loop doesn't use brackets (`{}`) nor indentation, therefore only `prevcar = nextcar` will be executed an infinite amount of times.
- you use `>2`;
- there is a cornercase where the linked list can be empty as well.

A probably better way to handle this:

```
public String removeBoxcarFromEnd() {
    String result;
    if(head == null) {  //empty list
        return null;      //or do something else? throw an exception?
    } else if (head.next() == null) {  //one element, remove it
        int result = head.data();
        head = null;
    }    
    else {  //more elements
        Boxcar prevcar = head, nextcar = head.next(), ffcar = nextcar.next();
        while (ffcar != null) {  //double next iteration
            prevcar = nextcar;
            nextcar = ffcar;
            ffcar = ffcar.next();
        }
        int result = nextcar.data(); //get result
        prevcar.setNext(null);       //remove it from the linked list
    }
    size--;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be `public int removeBoxcarFromEnd() {...}`.

Comment: @pzaenger: indeed, too much copy-pasta ;)

Comment: @CommuSoft int result = head.data(); says "String cannot be converted into and int". What goes on here?

Comment: @CodyMasyk-Jackson: based on your question, it looked as if it was an `int`. Now one can simply do a `s/int/String/g` (replcate `int` by `String`). and `s/-1/null/`.

Comment: @CommuSoft This still fails the tests I have to run. Which creates a box car, or two, and delete them according to the last place.

Comment: @CodyMasyk-Jackson: then provide the test data, the class files, the way you construct the linked list, etc. Why do you make it so complicated...

Comment: @CommuSoft The first is the boxcar class. The second is the test class. The third is the SingleLinkedList class. If this helps. Sorry for making it difficult. First time user.       [link]http://pastebin.com/EcsRnZ0T [link]http://pastebin.com/iYzbN0XR [link]http://pastebin.com/EYk4LZpN

Comment: @CommuSoft Moving the 'size--;' after the brackets worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to fetch data, only remove the last `Boxcar`:

```
public void removeBoxcarFromEnd() {
    Boxcar prevcar = head;
    Boxcar nextcar = head;

    if (head == null || head.next() == null) {
        return;
    }
    while (nextcar.next() != null) {
        prevcar = nextcar;
        nextcar = nextcar.next();
    }
    prevcar.setNext(null);
}
```

First we check for a null or one-element list; in those cases, there's nothing to do.

Next we walk the list until we get to the end (i.e. `nextCar.next()` returns null).  At each step, we save the `Boxcar` that we're passsing.

When we exit the loop, `prevcar` points to the second-to-last car, and we can safely set its `next` variable to `null`.